# Is there any difference in setState when using concat versus assigning the value directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

export default class DoctorData extends Component {
  state = {
    sidebarOpen: true,
    courseData: [],
    renderData: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let jwtToken = { accessToken: "" };
    axios.post(" ", jwtToken).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({
        courseData: data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2
      });
    });
  }

  RenderComponent = () => {
    console.log("we are inside sideBarComponet");
    return (
      <div className="card">
        {this.state.courseData.map((value, key) => {
          console.log(value);
          console.log("we are inside key", key);
          //   console.log(value.userLessonDetails[key].userChapterDetails[0].chapter.content)
          return (
            <div>
              <div className="card-header">
                <h4>Doctor-content</h4>
                <ReactPlayer
                  url={
                    value.userLessonDetails[0].userChapterDetails[0].chapter
                      .content
                  }
                  playing
                />
                {console.log(
                  "we are printing the content",
                  value.userLessonDetails[0].userChapterDetails[0].chapter
                    .content
                )}
                {console.log(typeof this.state.courseData)}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.courseData.length ? (
          <div>{this.RenderComponent()}</div>
        ) : null}
        {console.log("fghjkl", this.state.courseData)}
        {this.state.courseData.length}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In The above code I am just getting the data from my api and  using setState to store the data and I am rendering through it

1. These step is quite confusing

   ```
     componentDidMount() {
       let jwtToken = { accessToken: "" };
       axios.post(" ", jwtToken).then(data => {
         console.log(data);
         this.setState({
           courseData: this.state.courseData.concat(
             data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2
           )
         });
       });
     }
   ```

   I used concat to assign the data in setState
2. Before that i used

   ```
   this.setState({
     courseData: data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2
   })
   ```
3. I taught both are same, but while using `courseData: data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2`
   my page is not playing the video  is there any difference? but why media is to playing in the following scenario.
4. I tried to `console.log` the content, in both the cases the content is same (showing the mp4 file)
5. First I am getting the object type from axios so I am slicing the needed data and storing in the `setState`.

Comment: There is no magic to setState: you give it an object with key/value pairs, and it updates your state with them. It doesn't matter _how_ you build that object, the only thing that matters is what the object is by the time it's handed off to the setState function.

Comment: `.concat` creates a new array with the values of both the old `this.state.courseData` values and the new values received. Since the initial state is empty, both result in the same. But if you were to fetch again, like when paginating, it would then keep the old values as well as the new one if used with `concat`.

Comment: What is the content of `data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
>   does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

Which confirms it is safe to use within an immutable update of the state.

Note that it works the same for any values passed as arguments, but kind of flattens arrays.

> The `concat` method creates a new array consisting of the elements in
>   the object on which it is called, followed in order by, for each
>   argument, the elements of that argument (if the argument is an array)
>   or the argument itself (if the argument is not an array). It does not
>   recurse into nested array arguments.

```
[1].concat(['test'])   //=> [1, "test"]
[1].concat('test')     //=> [1, "test"]
[1].concat([['test']]) //=> [1, ["test"]]
```

`.concat` creates a new array with the values of both the old `this.state.courseData` values and the new values received. Since the initial state is an empty array `[]`, both result in the same **unless `data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2` is NOT an array**.

```
this.state.courseData.concat(data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2)
```

is equivalent to

```
[].concat(newValues)
// or just
newValues // if array
[newValues] // if something else
```

So both are the same, but `.concat` is just unnecessary here since it gets called only once within `componentDidMount` **unless** `this.state.courseData` gets prepopulated with default data from props or elsewhere.

---

## It doesn't work when removing `.concat`?

It means that `data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2` is probably not an array, and you're expecting one in the render method, but it's not anymore when the axios call succeeds (and after the `setState`).

```
this.setState({
  courseData: this.state.courseData.concat(
    data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2
  )
})
//=> [data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2]

this.setState({
  courseData: data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2
})
//=> data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2
```

---

That being said, it could be useful to use `.concat` if, say, you were adding a "fetch more" feature.

```
onFetchMore = (offset) => {
  fetchMoreAxiosCall(offset)
    .then(newData => this.setState(({ courseData }) => ({ 
      courseData: courseData.concat(newData)
    })))
}
```

You can update only the value you want within the state without spreading the old state (`{ ...state, courseData: /**/ }`) since ([source](http://courseData)):

> The output of the updater is shallowly merged with state.

Comment: but why i am unable to play my video  here is my token as well as api if you want to give a try 

 let jwtToken = { "accessToken": "78905c92-1ea8-49c0-8649-9b517b662c2c" }
        axios.post(' https://stgapi.omnicuris.com/api/v2/course/userCourseDetails/clinical-nutrition

Comment: @lostcoder I'm now addressing the most likely problem with `concat` that you could be having.

Answer (score 0):

[State updates should be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Instead React offers the `previousState` by passing a function which accepts the previous state as first argument e.g.

```js
// general
this.setState((oldState) => ({ ...oldState }));

// useful for updating objects
this.setState(({ myObject }) => ({ 
    myObject: { ...myObject, propToUpdate: true }
  })
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this is relevant?

Comment: Because you wrote
```
                this.setState({
                    courseData:this.state.courseData.concat(data.data.courseDetails.userModuleDetailsV2)
                })
            })
```

Comment: OP is asking about `concat` or not in the `setState`.

Comment: plese go through my question properlly i know that we should use a call back my doubt is using concat vs normally assigning the data @Julian

Comment: @EmileBergeron can you answer my question